# What's the difference between using & vs MOD operators in calculating indexes (Hash Table implementation)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashmap, hashcode

For general hash table implementation:

- Compute the hash of the key,
  `hash(key)=hashcode`
- Map the hashcode to the table/array.
  `hashcode % array_length = index`
- once we get the index, we add a node (the key, value, update next pointer) in the Linked List at that index.

So, the question is, what's the difference between:

```
def _get_index(self, key):

   # compute the hashcode
   hash_code = hash(key)
   array_index = hash_code & 15  # FIXME : why?
   return array_index
```

and

```
 array_index = hash_code % 15
```

For example:
for INPUT:

```
hm =MyHashMap()
hm.put("1", "sachin")
hm.put("2", "sehwag")
hm.put("3", "ganguly")
print(hm.get("1"))
print(hm.get("2"))
print(hm.get("3"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
sachin
sehwag
ganguly
```

'&' operator instead of '%' that doesn't make sense to me? because it doesn't work always as % operator in computing the index, But, I have seenn developer using `&` in some implementations of Hashtable

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_index = hash_code & 15
```

is equivalent to (on positive values):

```
array_index = hash_code % 16
```

it only works in the case when all significant bits of the number are ones (which is when the number is of the form `2**n - 1`).

Both remove the highest part of the number bits.

Bit-masking is way faster than division. So it's used when possible to speed up computations. Every time you see:

```
b = a % modulo
```

with `a > 0` and `modulo` is a power of 2 (`modulo == 2**n`), you can write:

```
b = a & (modulo-1)
```

instead. If the modulo is not a power of 2, then it cannot be done that way (and compiled languages optimizers often substitute power of 2 modulos or divisions/multiplications by the faster bit masking/shifting operation)

Even if it's true that bit-masking is way faster than division/modulus in assembly language, python is interpreted and that speed optimization is not really noticeable. Anyway if the intent is to mask bits, `&` operator makes more sense.

Comment: For a Python `int` object, though, the speed difference between `x % 16` and `x & 15` is minimal.

Comment: probably, but why making it slower?

Comment: I've had test runs where *`&`* was slightly slower. The overhead of dealing with Python objects appears to overwhelm whatever differences there might be in the underlying arithmetic.

Comment: lesson #1: avoid premature optimization :) If you code your routine in assembly, masks will be faster. Otherwise, compilers will take care of that. And Python will just do whatever it pleases.